# How to avoid multiple ngIf in Angular's template

Tags: templates, angular, design-patterns, generator, angular-ng-if

I'd like to know what is the best way to avoid using multiple *ngIf in template. For example, in a component's template, depends on the route, i have to generate multiple different elements like that:

```ts
<div *ngIf="route == 'page1'">Title for page 1</div>
<div *ngIf="route == 'page2'">Title for page 2</div> 

<i *ngIf="route == 'page1'" class="fa fa-message"></i>
<i *ngIf="route == 'page2'" class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>

<div *ngIf="route == 'page1'">
    <button>...</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="route == 'page2'">
    <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

It'll become messy soon, so i came up with a solution, in this component's ts file, i defined an array:

```ts
arr_1 = [
    { type: "text", content: "Title for page 1" },
    { type: "icon", class: "fa fa-message" },
    { type: "button", content: "..." }
]

arr_2 = [
    { type: "text", content: "Title for page 2" },
    { type: "icon", class: "fa fa-bell-o" },
    { type: "menu", menu_children: [...], class: "menu" }
]
```

In its template:

```ts
<div *ngIf="route == 'page1'">
    <generator *ngFor="let ele of arr_1"
        [type]="ele.type"
        [class]="ele.class"
        [content]="ele.content"
        [menu_children]="ele.menu_children"
    >
    </generator>
</div>

<div *ngIf="route == 'page2'">
    <generator *ngFor="let ele of arr_2"
        [type]="ele.type"
        [class]="ele.class"
        [content]="ele.content"
        [menu_children]="ele.menu_children"
    >
    </generator>
</div>
```

And i created a GeneratorComponent that receives the type and generate the corresponding element:

```ts
@Component({
     selector: 'generator',
     ...
})
export class GeneratorComponent {
    @Input() type: string;
    @Input() content: string;
    @Input() class: string;
    @Input() menu_children: string;
}
```

GeneratorComponent's template:

```ts
<div *ngIf="type == 'text'">{{ content }}</div>
<i *ngIf="type == 'text'">{{ content }}</i>
...
```

The problem here is the class GeneratorComponent will have multiple properties and they are not used for one reason (for example: content and menu_children have no relation).

Do you have any idea to fix my solution ? Other solutions will be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: ngSwitch maybe?

Comment: I don't get the problem with the `GeneratorComponent`

Answer (score 4):

You could use the helper element `<ng-container>`. It allows to apply structural directives `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, ..., without actually adding an element to the DOM

```ts
<ng-container *ngIf="route == 'page1'">
  <div>Title for page 1</div>
  <i class="fa fa-message"></i>
  <div>
    <button>...</button>
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="route == 'page2'">
  <div>Title for page 2</div> 
  <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
  <div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gunter I hadn't come across `ng-container`, that will be handy

Answer (score 0):

```
<div [ngSwitch]="route">
   <generator  ngSwitchWhen="page1" *ngFor="let ele of arr_1"
        [type]="ele.type"
        [class]="ele.class"
        [content]="ele.content"
        [menu_children]="ele.menu_children">
    </generator>
    <generator ngSwitchWhen="page2" *ngFor="let ele of arr_2"
        [type]="ele.type"
        [class]="ele.class"
        [content]="ele.content"
        [menu_children]="ele.menu_children">
    </generator>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it depends on route, why not have two components and display the right one based on the current route via `router-outlet`

i.e. have a Page1Component and Page2Component and configure routes for them in the appropriate routing.ts file

```
[
..
{
    path: 'page1',
    component: Page1Component,
  },
{
    path: 'page2',
    component: Page2Component,
  },
]
```

Then each Page component can define exactly what should be displayed.